# how to make custom view dial drawing numbers with trigonometry

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, trigonometry, android-graphics

Im trying to create an custom view that displays a dial with the numbers 1-10 around it. Im using trigonometry to find the X and Y positions for the numbers of the dial. I have no problems to find the positions around the circle but im unable to align them further in towards center of the dial. Look at number 6 for example, i just want it to be placed slightly above the thick white tick mark.

I have tried versions of "shortening the radius".

```
val diameter = Math.min(width, height)
val radius = diameter / 2 
val distance = radius * 0.20f //20% of radius
```

And then deduct 'distance' from radius to find the X and Y positions there and then add the numbers on those positions with no luck.

Below is the code that calculates the X and Y positions and adds the numbers displayed in the dial screenshot.

```
for (i in 1..10) {
canvas?.drawText(i.toString(),cx.toFloat() + 
(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees.getInt(feetNumber,0).toDouble())).toFloat()) *     
radius - (paint.measureText(i.toString()) / 2),
                cy.toFloat() + 
(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees.getInt(feetNumber,0).toDouble())).toFloat()) * 
radius + (paint.measureText(i.toString()) / 2), paint)

feetNumber++;
}
```

I have added the degrees in a array resource file.

```
<resources>
<array
  name="degrees">
  <item>270</item>
  <item>306</item>
  <item>342</item>
  <item>18</item>
  <item>54</item>
  <item>90</item>
  <item>126</item>
  <item>162</item>
  <item>198</item>
  <item>234</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

I would be very grateful if any one can help me to understand how to draw the numbers a short space after the thick tick marks where you usually find the numbers in a dial.

[image]

Comment: This is what i have been trying to do. However whatever i do with a 'shorter radius' the numbers just get drawn in strange arcs around the dial or partially around the dial. There is just something wrong with my calculations. The picture and code is the closest i get.

Comment: You mean to move origin from 0,0 in the device coordinate system and set origin at cy,cx in a local coordinate system draw and then restore?

Comment: use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) with circular positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. The problem was that i cant calulate the radius in the `canvas?.drawText()` so i needed to privide pre-calculated value.

```
val radius = diameter / 2
val mark = radius * 0.30f
val shorterRadius = radius - mark
```

and then use the `shorterRadius` inside `canvas?.drawText()` along with the rest of the calculations.

Then my dial look like the attached picture.

[image]